# From XML to JSON format with xml2js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) in order to convert some xml to json but I haven't succeed yet.

Look at the code then I will explain it

```
import xml2js, {parseString} from 'xml2js';

export default function (req, res) {

  request.execute('[dboSP].[somSP]', function spExecution (dataset) {
    connection.close();

      parseString(request.parameters.Dealer_Param.value, function(err, res) {
        request.parameters.Dealer_Param.value = res;
      })

      if (request.parameters.output_IS_SUCCESSFUL.value) {
        res.status(200).json({
          success : 'New dealer successfully inserted.'
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

you see a param `dataset` which returns this

```
[[{"":["<Dealers><Detail DealerName=\"marcelo test\" CardId=\"1222\" NickName=\"marcelo1312\" Active=\"1\" LegalId=\"16545\" TypeId=\"1\"/></Dealers>",true,"New dealer successfully inserted."]}]]
```

as you see there is a `XML` property which is the one I need to convert to JSON. Now, this `request.parameters.Dealer_Param.value` returns only this:

`<Dealers><Detail DealerName = "marcelo test" CardId = "1222" NickName = "marcelo1312" Active = "1" LegalId = "16545" TypeId = "1"></Detail></Dealers>`

so, what should I do in this case in order to convert this param into JSON ? the way I am doing it doesn't work.